# Combine multiple lines when one doesn't end with a dot

Tags: python, string

I am cleaning up some subtitles text and I am looking for a way to combine in a single line different lines, when they don't end with a ".". Considering the example

```
No, he's building one actually. 
Baller. 
Anyway, he's also offering a hundred k to people willing to skip or drop out of college
To pursue their idea.
```

I would like to convert it into

```
No, he's building one actually. 
Baller. 
Anyway, he's also offering a hundred k to people willing to skip or drop out of college to pursue their idea.
```

So that every line ends with a dot. Do you have suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a lookbehind to assert for example a lowercase char a-z, then match the newline and use a capture group for an uppercase char A-Z on the next line.

In the replacement use `lower()` on the capture group and prepend a space so that the matched newline is not part of the replacement.

```
import re

s = ("No, he's building one actually. \n"
                "Baller. \n"
                "Anyway, he's also offering a hundred k to people willing to skip or drop out of college\n"
                "To pursue their idea.")

s = re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])\r?\n([A-Z])", lambda x: " " + x.group(1).lower(), s)
print(s)
```

Output

```
No, he's building one actually. 
Baller. 
Anyway, he's also offering a hundred k to people willing to skip or drop out of college to pursue their idea.
```

---

Another option could be for example to assert a non whitspace char except a dot `[^\s.]` to the left to make it a bit broader.

```
(?<=[^\s.])\r?\n([A-Z])
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I loaded the text from a txt using ".read()", and if I run your commands things don't get fixed... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @albus_c I have tested it with `with open('yourfile', 'r') as f:
     s = f.read()
     s = re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])\r?\n([A-Z])", lambda x: " " + x.group(1).lower(), s)
     print(s)` and it works for me. Are you sure there are no extra spaces in the data? You might also try `(?<=[a-z])[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n([A-Z])` to match optional spaces after the last lowercase char.

Comment: you shouldn't need `\r?` since python standardizes line endings by default

Comment: @DillonDavis Thank you for your comment, I was not aware of that. As it is optional, it should not matter in this case.

Comment: @the-fourth-bird I have a few empty lines which I am dealing with using `text = os.linesep.join([s for s in text.splitlines() if s])`. That's the only difference I have from your script (I still don't get the result I would like to see)

Comment: @albus_c With that line, I get the same expected output. Not sure if it matters, but I am testing this on Ubuntu with this code. `with open('yourfile', 'r') as f:
     s = f.read()
     text = os.linesep.join([s for s in s.splitlines() if s])
     s = re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n([A-Z])", lambda x: " " + x.group(1).lower(), text)
     print(s)`

Comment: Are there also no spaces before the uppercase A-Z? Try `(?<=[a-z])[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*([A-Z])`

Answer (score 2):

**codes:**

```
file = open("your_file_name.txt","r").readlines()

list_1 = []
list_2 = []

for i in file:
    if i[-1] == "\n":
        list_1.append(i[:-1])
    else:
        list_1.append(i)

count = 0
not_add_count = None
for i in list_1:
    if count != not_add_count:
        if i[-1] == ".":
            list_2.append(i)
        else:
            list_2.append(i+" "+list_1[count+1].lower())
            not_add_count=count+1


    count +=1

for i in list_2:
    print(i)
```

**summary:**

**we separated the line break headers at first.We put the dot ending in a separate list (unless this sentence comes after a sentence that does not end with a dot, the purpose of not_add_count is to indicate the location of this sentence). then we printed everything that was filtered clean.**

**NOTE:**

**The purpose in this answer is just to show another way**